# How to send the failure file when user types already exists emailid

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, unix, mailchimp

Error: Request aborted
at onaborted (C:\Users\Bivek\OneDrive\Desktop\Newsletter-Signuo\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1052:15)
at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\Bivek\OneDrive\Desktop\Newsletter-Signuo\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1094:9)
at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:476:21) {
code: 'ECONNABORTED'

HERE IS THE CODE I HAD WROTE:

```
const Express = require("express");                 

const body_parser = require("body-parser");

const https = require("https");                    // To send request to external server

const app = Express();

app.use(Express.static("public"));                // To make our static website to dynamic website so that we can load other local path file like css and js

app.use(body_parser.urlencoded({extended:true}));   //if we don't use this then we can't able to fetch data of input

app.get("/",function(req,res){

    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html");

});

app.post("/",function(req,res){
    const FirstName = req.body.first;    
    const LastName = req.body.last;    
    const Email = req.body.email;
    const data = {                              // We need to create members for those who subscribed our signup
        members:[{                              // here is the syntax
            email_address:Email, 
            status: "subscribed",
            merge_fields:{
                FNAME: FirstName,
                LNAME: LastName,
            }
            
        }]
    } 
    const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);           // change the javascript data to string data so that mailchimp can recognise it
    const url = "https://us18.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/92a6b8971c";    
    const option = {                                
        method: "POST",
        auth: "Bivek:a40acb902c010418f36154cb92f63edb-us18"
    };
    const request = https.request(url,option,function(response){   // earlier we use https.get for getting data from the external server but here we need to post data to mailchimp server that's why we used https.request
        response.on("data",function(data){
            const errors = JSON.parse(data).errors;
            if(errors){
                res.sendFile(__dirname + "/failure.html",function(err){
                    console.log(err);
                });
            }
            else{
                res.sendFile(__dirname + "/success.html");
            }
        });
        if (response.statusCode === 200) {
            res.sendFile(__dirname + "/success.html");
        }
        else{
            res.sendFile(__dirname + "/failure.html");
        }
        
    }); 
    request.write(jsonData);
    request.end();
})
app.post("/failure",function(req,res){
    res.redirect("/");
})
app.listen("3000",function(){

    console.log("Server is running at port 3000");

});
// Audience ID: 92a6b8971c
```

after execution of console.log(err) statement it shows the above error
When user inputs the already exists email-id to signup then I want to send failure.html file.

Comment: Rather than sending files have to tried using a render engine to render your HTML files or if you don't want to you could create separate routes for success and failure where you send those files and in the post request redirect it to the corresponding route. 

P.S. Always return your response so that request stops when you want to send a file or response to front end.

Comment: can you be more specific with an example

Comment: Without ejs if you are doing it first I would add 2 new routes one for success and 1 for failure `app.get("/failure", function (req, res) {
 return res.sendFile(__dirname + "/failure.html");
});` then in place of `res.sendFile(__dirname + "/failure.html",function(err){
                    console.log(err);
                });` I would simply redirect the request to the failure route like `return res.redirect("/failure");`